# string to UTF-8 conversion in C++

Tags: c++, utf-8

I have a string `Test\xc2\xae` represented in Hex as `0x54 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x5c 0x78 0x63 0x32 0x5c 0x78 0x61 0x65`.
The character set `\xc2\xae` in this string is nothing but the UTF-8 Encoding of ® (registered trademark).

I want to write a c++ function which can convert `\xc2` (in Hex `0x5c 0x78 0x63 0x32`) character set to hex value `0xc2`.

e.g. I want to write a c++ function which can convert `Test\xc2\xae` [`0x54 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x5c 0x78 0x63 0x32 0x5c 0x78 0x61 0x65`] to `Test®` [`0x54 0x65 0x73 0x74 0xc2 0xae`]

Comment: Just to be sure, does the target font include the required character glyphs?

Comment: It is not clear to me if you have the binary representation of the initial string to work with or you are starting with the literal string.

Comment: I don't know how to rewrite the following Python code to C++: `'Test\\xc2\\xae'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'unicode-escape').encode( 'latin1').decode( 'utf-8')` (returns `'Test®'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I think that you try to convert each `\x??` sequence (four chars), where `??` is a sequence of two hexadecimal digits, to a unique char with the value which was expressed in hexadecimal.

If you don't have to use huge libraries dedicated to this, maybe this trivial algorithm could do the trick.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::string
convert_backslash_x(const std::string &str)
{
  auto result=std::string{};
  for(auto start=std::string::size_type{0};;)
  {
    const auto pos=str.find("\\x", start);
    if((pos==str.npos)||  // not found
       (pos+4>size(str))) // too near from the end
    {
      // keep the remaining of the string
      result.append(str, start);
      break;
    }
    // keep everything until this position
    result.append(str, start, pos-start);
    const auto c1=std::tolower(str[pos+2]), c2=std::tolower(str[pos+3]);
    if(std::isxdigit(c1)&&std::isxdigit(c2))
    {
      // convert two hex digits to a char with this value
      const auto h1=std::isalpha(c1) ? 10+(c1-'a') : (c1-'0');
      const auto h2=std::isalpha(c2) ? 10+(c2-'a') : (c2-'0');
      result+=char(h1*16+h2);
      // go on after this \x?? sequence
      start=pos+4; 
    }
    else
    {
      // keep this incomplete \x sequence as is
      result+="\\x";
      // go on after this \x sequence
      start=pos+2;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int
main()
{
  for(const auto &s: {"Test\\xc2\\xae",
                      "Test\\xc2\\xae Test\\xc2\\xae",
                      "Test\\xc2\\xa",
                      "Test\\x\\xc2\\xa"})
  {
    std::cout << '(' << s << ") --> (" << convert_backslash_x(s) << ")\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @beparas It's `start=0`, with the type [`std::string::size_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for `start`. We could have [omitted the explicit zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization); `{}` would have been the same.

Comment: @beparas This `for` loop has no condition, because it is not concise to express (see the `break;`) and no increment instruction since there are two possibilities (`pos+4` or `pos+2`) depending on what happened in the body of this loop ; `start` is made local to this loop because we don't need it outside.

Comment: Thanks ones again for your quick response, 
While compiling I am getting error: 
```error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::append(const string&, long unsigned int&)’
result.append(str,start);```

Comment: @beparas Which compiler (and version) do you use?

Comment: it may be g++ v7, let me check it, I want to run this program on iMX CPU. Getting above error when cross compiling the program.
Note: error says ```std::__cxx11::...```

Comment: @beparas Try to adapt from one of [these overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) if one is supported by your development environment.

Comment: I am using ```aarch64-poky-linux``` toolchain, with g++ version ```aarch64-poky-linux-g++ (GCC) 7.3.0```

Comment: getting same error when I am using this online compiler. 
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: I replace ```result.append(str, start);``` this line with ```result.append(str, start, str.size() - start);``` and it is working.

Comment: @beparas Yes, gcc 7.3 supports `-std=c++17` but does not support the overload number 9 (in the documentation) of `append()`... May be the support of C++17 by gcc 7.3 was not complete.